# SQL select records based on collection result from another query

Tags: sql

I am stuck a bit on this step: there are two tables:
booking (bookingId, id, userId)
timetableSlot (id,classId)

"id"  linkes both tables.

Task - to show all classes,booked by user.
In the Servlet i can select all bookings for particular user from the booking table:

```
    int userId=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("loggedInUserId"));

    BookingDB allUserBookings = new BookingDB();
    Collection<BookingDB> userBookings = new ArrayList<BookingDB>();
    userBookings = allUserBookings.displayUserBookings(userId);
```

The result is a collection of records for one user bookings with many timetable slot ids. How can I pass all those ids to select corresponding records from timetableSlot table? Select collection based on collection? Thank you

Comment: Your code has no SQL in it.  Are you sure that is the right tag for this?  If so, you might want to show the queries you are using.

Comment: Hi, this code is from the servlet to retreive all bookings. I used this sql for it:    SELECT * FROM booking where userId=?  It returns collection

Comment: How to go about the next step :SELECT * FROM timetableSlot where id=results from previous query?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM timetableSlot where id in (select id from "previous query")`

Comment: Don't post code in comments. [edit] your question. Also: which DBMS are you using? What is the definition of the tables? What is the expected output of the query?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `ttslot` WHERE id IN (

SELECT id FROM booking WHERE booking.userId=76
)